# Parse.com CLI tool ignores CSS files upon deploy

Tags: css, parse-platform, command-line-interface

I've done the basic tutorials for setting up a website on Parse with success. Now I am trying to add CSS. However, when I use `parse deploy`, the file gets ignored:

```
Uploading recent changes to scripts...
The following files will be uploaded:
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/app.js
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/main.js
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/views/hello.ejs
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/views/main.ejs
The following files will be ignored:
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/.DS_Store
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/css/.DS_Store
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/css/main.css  <-------
/Users/clintonburgos/Documents/Code/MyApp/cloud/views/.DS_Store
Finished uploading files
```

This also is the case when I move it to the `/cloud` or the `/views` directories. Any ideas why this may be happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from their [doc](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#hosting):

> our Express app can sit side-by-side with any static content you
>   deployed from your public folder. When a request goes to a URL of your
>   subdomain, Parse will first look for a matching file in the public
>   directory

uplaod your static content in `public` folder and everything will work fine